# how to get HTML TAG value from HTML String.?

Tags: android, html

I am getting one string like below from server in response.

```
   "<div class=\"ExternalClass00BD08C9929B4EE8A7A9A6E9CA27A68C\"><p>\u200bTesting by Android<a href=\"/sites/Android/Shared%20Documents/1.txt\">1.txt</a><a href=\"/sites/Android/Shared%20Documents/2.txt\">2.txt</a><br></p></div>"
```

Now I want To get From this **href** value="/sites/Android/Shared%20Documents/1.txt\"

as well file name =1.txt which is enclosed in anchor tag

In short i want to split every value of HTML TAG

Is There anyway to Do this..??

If Yes then please give me suggetion how to achieve this...

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your response string format is consistent then you do as shown below.

```
String html = "<div class=\"ExternalClass00BD08C9929B4EE8A7A9A6E9CA27A68C\"><p>\u200bTesting by Android<a href=\"/sites/Android/Shared%20Documents/1.txt\">1.txt</a><a href=\"/sites/Android/Shared%20Documents/2.txt\">2.txt</a><br></p></div>";

String title = html.substring(html.indexOf("<p>") + 3, html.indexOf("<a"));
String[] splitHtml = html.split("<a");
for(int i = 0; i < splitHtml.length; i++) {

    if(splitHtml[i].contains("href=")) {
        String[] hrefSplit = splitHtml[i].split("\"");
        String url = hrefSplit[1];
        String fileName = hrefSplit[2].substring(hrefSplit[2].indexOf(">")+1,hrefSplit[2].indexOf("<")); 
    }
}
```

Comment: how to get this one "\u200bTesting by Android "??  I also want this messge

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper See edits. 'title' will have "Testing by Android"

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var hrefArray;
  $('.divClass').each(function() //if you will have more than 1 link
  {
    hrefArray = $(this).DupeHref(); //getting href
    hrefArray = hrefArray.split("/").pop(); //now you have cutted array :)
  });
});
```

Hope i helped